# Trying to link a seperate Serial C++ header to the Steam SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, steam

I'm trying to get serial communication to work through a Steam mod.  To take care of the serial communication in the Steam SDK's native C++ code, [I found a C++ Serial library based on Win32 here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C)

I've been playing around with it and it seems fine, but when I try to

```
 #include "Serial.h"
```

in a Steam SDK source code object, it seems like it doesn't recognize it.  I pointed the linker to the file, but I get dozens of "undeclared identifiers" and syntax errors in Serial.h when I go to compile.  Is this header file in a format that the Steam SDK can't read?  Is there an alternative to get serial communication in a Steam mod?

EDIT:  Sorry all, some details.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  When I go to compile, I get an error like

```
...\serial.h(91): error C2065: 'EV_BREAK' : undeclared identifier
```

for a definition like:

```
class CSerial
  {
  public:
    typedef enum
    {
        EEventBreak        = EV_BREAK,
```

It seems it catches almost every definition like this.  Then there's the smattering of syntax errors:

```
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(306): warning C4183: 'Write': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(311): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Read'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(311): error C2433: 'CSerial::LONG' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(311): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(311): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DWORD'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(311): warning C4183: 'Read': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(314): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Break'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(314): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(314): warning C4183: 'Break': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(329): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetLastError'
5>c:\users\eric\desktop\modding\test mod\source-sdk-2013-master\sp\src\game\server\serial.h(329): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I don't want to fill up the page, but there's on the order of about a hundred errors like this.  Overall there's just tons of syntax errors, which doesn't make sense, as I can make this header compile fine in another project.

Comment: what is the error? and can you post your source code? are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: It's not clear if you're having compiler issues or linker issues. Post the *exact* error you're getting. Syntax errors in Serial.h mean it's being found. Syntax errors aren't linker errors. What compiler are you using? Etc., etc., you need more information.

Comment: @Steve

After trying over and over, I couldn't get everything formatted in the comment box, so check my edit for more information.  Thanks for responding.